# Add active class to react component with Child links

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:

```
import React, { useEffect, PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import "./DesktopHeader.scss";

interface Props extends PropsWithChildren<any> {}

export default function DesktopHeader(props: Props) {
  const children = props.children;
  let pathname = window.location.pathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    pathname = window.location.pathname;
  }, [window.location.pathname]);

  return (
    <header className="header">
      <h1>Thank My Farmer</h1>
      <ul>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child: any, index: number) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {child}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </header>
  );
}
```

I am using it like that:

```
<DesktopHeader>
  <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="/settings">Projects</a>
  <a href="/some">Projects</a>
</DesktopHeader>
```

What I am trying now is to add an `active` class to the `<li>` or `<a>` element based on the URL.
So if I visit `/projects` I want to style the corresponding link but I dont know how to do it with Child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.cloneElement` to add a custom class to each child

```
React.cloneElement(child, {
  key: index,
  className: `${child.props.className} ${
    window.location.pathname.includes(child.props.href) ? "active" : ""
  }`
});
```